# crontab - mysqldump is using different socket

Tags: bash, mysql, cron, sockets

First, I have already permanently set the PATH directory of MySQL so I can use it in terminal in any directory. To verify this process, I restarted my computer, open the terminal and use the command `mysql`. I can also use `mysqldump` in any directory in terminal. I am using lampp, and it was installed in `/opt/lampp/`.

I have no problem at all when using mysql or mysqldump in terminal

What I don't understand, and what I want to fix is when using mysqldump in crontab.

So I have this script on my desktop, with the filename of `mysqldump.sh`. What's inside is; `mysqldump -u root thedatabase > /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/db_'date +\%Y'.sql 2> /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/crontab_error.log`

The problem here is the mysqldump is not working and is throwing me an error of: `mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect` which I don't understand why.

I have also tried to change the code in my script to; `(cd /opt/lampp/bin/ && mysqldump -u root thedatabase > /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/db_'date +\%Y'.sql 2> /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/crontab_error.log)` which still no luck.

what is wrong? why the crontab is using the socket of `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`? How can I fix that?

Anyway, the crontab is `*/1 * * * * /home/sfadmin/Desktop/mysqldump.sh`. This should execute mysqldump every minute.

Comment: Do you have a password associated to `root`?  It can be given various ways: environment variable, option `-p`, use a credential file...

Comment: nope, I didn't set any password. all the configurations are default.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I really don't know what's going on. Why it is using the socket of `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` which is doesn't exist in the first place. My guess is I made some mistakes in configuration where the previous `mysql-server` which I installed using `apt` is still in use. I don't know where to find the configuration or where should I set the new socket because the file `etc/my.cnf` doesn't exist anymore.

So what I did, is create a link of `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` then name the file to `mysqld.sock`. In my terminal I execute the following command line by line;

`cd /opt/lampp/var/mysql/`

`ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysqld.sock`

it is said the it needs to used the full path when creating a link to a file, otherwise, it won't work.

then I created a new directory of `mysqld` in `/var/run/`. Then I simply moved the `mysqld.sock` I created into `/var/run/mysqld/`.

that's it. the crontab is working fine, and the mysqldump command in bash script is working. however, I changed the command inside my `mysqldump.sh` into;

`mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -u root thedatabase > /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/db_'date +\%Y'.sql 2> /media/sfadmin/BACKUP/crontab_error.log`

everything is working now as expected.

**UPDATE** -
It turns out that the solution above is only temporary.

I tried restarting the computer and was surprised that the problem came back. I tried navigating to `/var/run/` but the `mysqld` directory I created no longer existed.

I tried to redo the same method above to fix the issue, but it is no longer working. The same issue with the socket even though the `mysqld.sock` has now existed in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.